# Rstudio-server on AWS ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, rstudio

Just installed Rstudio-server on AWS ubuntu instance (instructions written by Dean Attali) and all seems to Work fine but get the following message when terminating rstudio session and starting a new session. The error message: File listing Error....Error navigating to ~: Invalid json-rpc request.